# Path nomenclature in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Why this statement **works**:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.survivaltips.Diary.Activity" />
```

and this it **doesn't work**:

```
<activity android:name="com$example$survivaltips$Diary.Activity" />
<activity android:name="$Diary.Activity" />
```

I'm not able to find a logic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [the documentation for the `<activity>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) states that

> The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, `"com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"`)

Using a `.` as the package name qualifier is the only way to define a fully qualified package name.